# Avoid NullPointerException When JTable Exports to Excel File

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jtable, apache-poi

I have a JTable with no values (empty columns data). Like this,

```
|column 1|column 2|column 3|column 4|
-------------------------------------
|Java    |C#      |        |Ruby    |
-------------------------------------
|Java    |        |PHP     |Ruby    |
```

I am trying to export this JTable to an Excel File. When I press the button to export this it gives **NullPointerException**. Because of that null values. So I need to ignore it and continue exporting Excel Files.

Here is the code I used,

```
        XSSFWorkbook xb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet xs = xb.createSheet();

        //Load data to TreeMap
        TreeMap<String,Object[]> data = new TreeMap<>();

        //Add Rows and Cells
        data.put("-1", new Object[]{pageTable.getColumnName(0), pageTable.getColumnName(1), pageTable.getColumnName(2), pageTable.getColumnName(3), pageTable.getColumnName(4), pageTable.getColumnName(5), pageTable.getColumnName(6)});

        for(int i = 0; i<pageTable.getRowCount(); i++)
        {
            data.put(Integer.toString(i), new Object[]{getCellValue(i, 0), getCellValue(i, 1), getCellValue(i, 2), getCellValue(i, 3), getCellValue(i, 4), getCellValue(i, 5), getCellValue(i, 6)});
        }

        //Write data to Excel
        Set<String> ids = data.keySet();
        XSSFRow row;
        int rowID = 0;

        for(String key: ids)
        {
            row = xs.createRow(rowID++);

            //Get data as per Key
            Object[] values = data.get(key);

            int cellID = 0;
            for(Object o: values)
            {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellID++);
                cell.setCellValue(o.toString());
            }
        }
```

And getCellValue Method;

```
private String getCellValue(int x, int y)
{
    return pageTable.getValueAt(x, y).toString();
}
```

And it gives this row is the cause,

```
data.put(Integer.toString(i), new Object[]{getCellValue(i, 0), getCellValue(i, 1), getCellValue(i, 2), getCellValue(i, 3), getCellValue(i, 4), getCellValue(i, 5), getCellValue(i, 6)});
```

So How can I fix it? Any way to avoid this?

Thanks for the help in advance! Best Regards.

Comment: Need to know what getCellValue method is doing.

Comment: @aglassman I am really Sorry. I forgot to add that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are saying that some values can be null, so in this for loop,

```
for(Object o: values)
{
    Cell cell = row.createCell(cellID++);
    cell.setCellValue(o.toString());
}
```

o.toString() must be causing NullPointerException.

Just change second line in for loop from,

```
cell.setCellValue(o.toString());
```

to

```
cell.setCellValue(o==null?"":o.toString());
```

And this should avoid NPException and your code should work fine.

Let me know if this works fine else will help you further.

Edit 1:

Just read again and saw you suspecting your NPE in this method.

```
private String getCellValue(int x, int y)
{
    return pageTable.getValueAt(x, y).toString();
}
```

If this return statement is causing this, then don't call toString method without checking null value from getValueAt and change your method to this,

```
private String getCellValue(int x, int y)
{
    if( pageTable.getValueAt(x, y) == null) {
        return "";
    } else {
        pageTable.getValueAt(x, y).toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this But it keeps getting the error. can you help me to avoid this?

Comment: Yes just edited my answer to avoid another NullPointerException in getCellValue method. Try that and it should work. If it still doesn't, then please update your post and add exception stack trace to show what line and which method it is running into NPE

Comment: Pleased to know it helped :)